# Sitemap still contains URLs of deleted pages

Tags: uri, xml-sitemap

I've deleted some products from my commerce kickstart database by means of standard Drupal commerce kickstart tools. But it looks like something gone wrong. Because some deleted pages URLs are still in sitemap,so Google webmaster tools tell me about 404 pages.

I've rebuilt sitemap n+1 times but those URLs are still here.

What tables should I check to find tails have to be deleted manually? What tables does the sitemap module use to build sitemap file?

Comment: Did you trigger the cron?

Comment: xmlsitemap module?

Comment: The cron works properly. Yes,xmlsitemap module.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the XMLSitemap module, uninstall it and run cron to delete its tables from the database, then reinstall it, it will generate the right urls

Comment: Well,I'll try to do, what you advised. Well, but something tells me that those, deleted product records "tails" will generate 404 pages again.

Comment: And I could clear xml module tables manually, is it any need to delete xmlmap module?